# haxis.format not working in chartkick

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, chartkick

Setting the option for [`hAxis.format`](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js#options) with [`chartkick`](http://chartkick.com/), is not affecting the generated chart.

What am i doing wrong to change the format or is something broken on [`chartkick's`](http://chartkick.com/) end?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yekLh/5/)

Comment: `hAxis` values need to be actual dates, not strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from `discrete` to `continuous` fixed the issue.